How to Upload a Video Files Template in GrapesJS?
I'm working with GrapeJS for a project and have successfully implemented custom image upload functionality using the  tag. Now, I need to do something similar for videos. Specifically, I want to:
Add a video template (like a  tag) to the editor.
Allow users to upload a video file and set the video source dynamically.
Ensure the video appears in the GrapeJS canvas after upload (just like how an image would appear with the  tag).
My question is: how can I upload the video template itself, so users can interact with it within the GrapeJS editor?
Is there a built-in way or plugin to achieve this in GrapeJS? If not, can you suggest a custom solution for adding video components with upload functionality in GrapeJS?
Any guidance or examples would be appreciated!
https://grapesjs.com/demo this link
[![enter image description here]
I am trying to implement a feature where a video tag can be dragged to a specific area. When the user clicks on the video frame, a file upload dialog opens, allowing them to select a video file (e.g., MP4). After selecting the file, I want to convert it to Base64 format and set the src attribute of the video tag to this Base64 string
My question is: how can I upload the video template itself, so users can interact with it within the GrapeJS editor?

You can use this to add video tag.
self.editor.DomComponents.addType('video', {
        model: {
            defaults: {
                tagName: 'video',
                style: { width: '100%', height: '100%' },
                traits: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        label: 'Source',
                        name: 'src',
                        changeProp: 1,
                    }
                ],
                stylable: ['width', 'height'],
            }
        },
        view: {
            events: {
                'dblclick': 'clickOnElement'
            },
            init() {
                this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:target', this.updateTarget);
            },
            updateTarget(src) {
                this.model.set('src', src);
            },
            clickOnElement(ev) {
                const editor = self.editor;
                const assetManager = editor.AssetManager;
                assetManager.open();
            }
        }
    });

The Asset Manager Modal will pop up when adding new video to the iframe.
When DbClicking the video inside the iframe, by default, no modal will pop up, thats why I'm adding events section to the view object to call ClickOnElement and opens the modal again.
One more thing, when changing video url we have to notify the model by calling :
const selectedAsset = self.editor.AssetManager.get(videoURL);
const selectedComp = self.editor.getSelected();
selected.getView().updateTarget(self.selectedAsset.getSrc());


MohameD ELQUCHIRI Thanks for your suggestion, but it didn’t fully resolve the issue. I found another way to fix it by adding events to trigger the modal when double-clicking the video in the iframe. Thanks again for your help!
